# Mantaflow in Blender: Help with understanding the vertices values in the generated mesh files

Tags: export, fluid-simulation, file-format

I'm currently trying to acheive the following: I'm using Mantaflow + Blender to create a fluid simulation. Then I'm exporting it as Alembic, and import it into Unreal Engine (Aka ue4). In UE4 I want to know the exact position of the simulated fluid (the exact position of the vertices.) The reason I want to know this is to build some sort of ray tracing with the generated simulation because UE4 doesn't support line tracing of animated meshes.

My plan now is to use the coordinates of the vertices of the fluid simulation, and then scale them so that they match the scale in UE4. But I don't really understand what the numbers mean.
An example of a vertice in the generated mesh file is this:

```
v -0.457893 -0.226563 -0.101563
```

I notice that the numbers don't seem to get higher then 0.45 or lower then -0.45. Does anybody know how I could convert these numbers into another scale, like for instance in UE4? Why is blender+mantaflow using these numbers and not something else? Is there anywhere I can read about this, or perhaps look at the source code to try to understand it?